# TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given Python 3?

Tags: python

I am unable to figure out what is causing this strange error. To me it looks like I am providing the right number of args but I have no idea why I am getting such an exception.

```
class FileParser(object):

    def __init__(self,file_name,category):
        self.file_name=file_name
        self.category=category



class SchoolParser(FileParser):

    def __init__(self,file_name,category):
        FileParser.__init__(self,file_name,category)
```

views.py

```
schoolparser = SchoolParser(file_name,category)
```

logs

```
 schoolparser = SchoolParser(file_name,category)
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't show anything that would produce that error. Try deleting your `.pyc` files and restarting Python, and make sure you're looking at the right files.

Comment: Did you update the code  at runtime or something ?

Comment: You should consider using `super().__init__(file_name, category)` instead.

Comment: The code works perfectly, Did you post the correct code, but as a suggestion, use `super` to call your superclass constructor `super().__init__(file_name,category)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get this error but a different error. That was because after the class is created, you need to instantiate it with an object which in your case will be the name of file and category.

```
>>>class FileParser(object):
       def __init__(self,file_name,category):
           self.file_name=file_name
           self.category=category

   class SchoolParser(FileParser):
       def __init__(self,file_name,category):
           FileParser.__init__(self,file_name,category)

>>>schoolparser = SchoolParser(file_name,category)

   NameError: name 'file_name' is not defined
```

This was because I was not instantiating the class with proper arguments. This got it done:

```
>>>schoolparser = SchoolParser('banana', 'fruit')

   <__main__.SchoolParser at 0x1bf159ed860>
```

Hope it helps.